# How to COMPLETELY hide the drawer hamburger in Android?

Tags: android, drawer

I have a drawer in my Android App. The drawer has a hamburger icon on the left side of the toolbar. I want to hide the hamburger icon. I use the following code:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

The hamburger disappear, however, there is still a white space left, as is shown in the following img.

[image: Here is the hamburger, an icon for drawer]
[image: there is still a white space on the left side of Toolbar]

How can I make the white space disappear?

Comment: what is the 'hamburger' icon. Please show/highlight the icon, so that we can remove ambiguity.

Comment: Can you show us your XML layout? Are you using a custom `ToolBar`?

Answer (score 5):

set your toolbar navigation icon to null.

```
 toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
```

[Refer doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) it says

> Parameters icon
>   Drawable to set, may be null to clear the icon

------------Update----------

If results remain same then create drawable of the color which is background  of your toolbar. And set it as navigation icon.This hack should work.

naviation_drawable_icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="YOUR_COLOR_CODE"/>
</shape>
```

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.naviation_drawable_icon).

Comment: Same result, hamburger disappear, but a white space still there.